# Arithmetic using decimals python

Tags: python, jython

I save a number inside a variable and then I want to to multiply that number by 0.5. But, it seems to change the type of the variable, is my variable being changed into a double or something of the sort? (I'm just beginning to learn python)

CODE & ERROR:

```
  a = pickAFile()
  b = makePicture(a)
  c = getWidth(b)
  d = getHeight(b)
  e = (c * 0.5)
  f = (d * 0.5)
--> (problem line) newPicture = makeEmptyPicture(e,f)
```

error: An attempt was made to call a function with a parameter of an invalid type. This means that you did something such as trying to pass a string to a method that is expecting an integer.

Comment: Can we see `makeEmptyPicture()`?

Comment: makeEmptyPicture is a built in method for Jython, I've used it successfully before without every creating it myself, it's meant to take in the height and width of a picture file, but, I can't seem to find the api for it, only examples of it in use.

Comment: Have you tried calling it using makeEmptyPicture(int(e), int(f))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The examples of makeEmptyPicture that I have been able to find seem to require an integer width and height. as a result, you should either use

```
makeEmptyPicture(int(e), int(f))
```

or round up using

```
makeEmptyPicture(int(math.ceil(e)), int(math.ceil(f)))
```

Note that math.ceil returns a float so you need to force it to an int in the call.

Answer (score 1):

Python variables do not have a set data type, so yes, Python can/will change the data type of your variable based on what you're assigning to it.

You can see the current type of the variable with:

```
type(var_name)
```

To be able to specifically answer your question, show us the definition of `makeEmptyPicture()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you multiply an odd integer by 0.5, you will get a non-integer result. You probably want to either round up or round down using `math.ceil` or `math.floor` and then convert that result to an integer with the `int` function.

Answer (score 0):

you should use floats:

```
    e=float(whatever you want inside)
```

this way it will allow python to use decimals otherwise it rounds them. You should use floats instead of of integers for your other variables too, of you want to make them decimals.

Comment: Python will force e and f to float because of the use of a float in the arithmetic expressions.